# Checking for duplicate lists at certain indices in a lists of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of indices, how do I check if the lists at those indices in a list of lists are the same or not?

```
# Given:
# indices = [0, 2, 3]
# lsts = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']]
# would test if ['A', 'B'] == ['A', 'B'] == ['B', 'C']
# would return False

# Given:
# indices = [0, 2]
# lsts = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']]
# would test ['A', 'B'] == ['A', 'B']
# would return True
```

I currently have:

```
for i in range(len(lsts)):
    for i in range(len(indices) - 1):
        if lsts[indices[i]] != lsts[indices[i + 1]]:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do it:

```
>>> indices = [0, 2, 3]
>>> lsts = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']]
>>> all(lsts[indices[0]] == lsts[i] for i in indices)
False
>>> indices = [0, 2]
>>> lsts = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']]
>>> all(lsts[indices[0]] == lsts[i] for i in indices)
True
```

By the way, thank you for providing clear examples of input and expected output.

Comment: No guarantee that `0` is in the indices, should use `all(lsts[indices[0]] == lsts[i] for i in indices)`